# Is there a way to determine the directory the file being executed resides in?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, asdf

And if so, is there way that asdf can import a symbol that is calculated in runtime.

I'm trying to to specify the directory on which the project resides so the test runner can find the input files and also when I run from the repl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, system-relative-pathname and system-source-directory are your friends. At least if you execute from source.

Comment: http://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/asdf/Miscellaneous-additional-functionality.html

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "execution".

If your code is executed when your file is loaded, take a look at [Variable `*LOAD-PATHNAME*`, `*LOAD-TRUENAME*`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/v_ld_pns.htm).

If you need the current working directory, `asdf` has `getcwd` and `chdir`.

Comment: Not the current working directory but the directory on which the .asd file resides

Comment: Well I found a way around it with the asdf:system-relative-pathname i.e. 
(asdf:system-relative-pathname :nclack-tests "specs")